# How to pass data between routes - not query params. Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 5, how can i pass data to the different component from different module.

I have tried shared service. Tried, replay subject, behavior subject, and subject. Data is getting vanished after route change. Please help.

**component1**

```
this.sharedService.setReferenceObject(data);
this.router.navigateByUrl('component2');
```

**sharedService**

```
export class SalesOrderService {

myReferenceSubj = new ReplaySubject<MyReference>(null);
public myReferenceSubj$ = this.myReferenceSubj.asObservable();

constructor(){}
  setReferenceObject(data: MyReference) {
    this.myReferenceSubj.next(data);
  }
}
```

**Component 2**

```
constructor(){
this.sharedService.myReferenceSubj$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data, "data++++") // returning null
          });
}
```

data getting as null. Is there any way that we can pass data with route, without queryparams?

Comment: Could you make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem?

Comment: ignore the code.. but do you have any idea how we can parse data from route.

Answer (score 1):

A year later with this reply but what helped me was I created a service and used dependency injection in the component I wanted the data to be passed to. After I injected the service I subscribed the data and saved it in the session storage. Using ngOnInit I retreived the last data stored in the sessions storage. Basically you need the page to retain the data somehow. That can be done either by creating a database to store the data, by getting the browser history or by the simplest method is by storing the data in the session storage (problem with this method is, if its sensitive data it will be exposed unless you can find a way to encode it.

```
constructor(private sharedService: SalesOrderService){}

retrievedData:any;

ngOnInit(){
  this.getData()
}

getData(){
 sessionStorage.clear()
 this.sharedService.myReferenceSubj$.subscribe(data => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('myData', data)
        this.retrievedData = sessionStorage.getItem('myData')
  });
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Dependency Injection syntax for creating "sharedService" instance inside Component 2 and make myReferenceSubj$ object of BehaviourSubject.

```
constructor(private sharedService: SalesOrderService){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.sharedService.myReferenceSubj$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data, "data++++") 
   });
}
```

Comment: Alright, so have you aded the decorator 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

in  SalesOrderService

Comment: in angular 5 you can't declare providedin root

Comment: Then, make sure the "SalesOrderService" is added inside "providers" array of root module

Comment: it is there.... My question is along with route how can we pass data